# Update problem: some index files failed to download from PPA

Tags: 11.10, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix a bad PPA installed in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89408/how-do-i-fix-a-bad-ppa-installed-in-ubuntu)

Error message:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bisigi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bisigi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```