# How do I fix a bad PPA installed in Ubuntu?

Tags: ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I installed this Pidgin PPA after a clean Ubuntu 11.10 64bit install:

https://launchpad.net/~pidgin-developers/+archive/ppa/+files/pidgin-ppa_0.0.5_all.deb

I installed it like this:

> sudo dpkg -i pidgin-ppa_0.0.5_all.deb

I think it worked then, because I believe my pidgin to had been updated back then.

Now when I do `apt-get update`, this is a part of the echo log:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What should I do to fix the above? It's very annoying. I think the easiest would be to erase the PPA, but I don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: Related question - http://askubuntu.com/questions/89174/404-errors-on-universe-ppas